razor model binding for one to many to many
I have an object called ChangeForm.  This object has two related items called ChangeType and ChangeFormChangeType. For brevity ill show only the important parts.
/* public class ChangeType {
    public Int16 ID { get; set; } = 0; // Primary Key
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; } = false; // Other properties
} */

public class ChangeFormChangeType
{
public int _CfID { get; set; } //foreign key
public Int16 _CtID { get; set; }    //foreign key
}

public class ChangeForm
{
 public Int CfID {get;set;} = 0; PK
}

*/
on my razor page:
<div class="col-12 changeTypeList">
    @if (Model.ChangeTypeList != null && Model.ChangeTypeList.Any()) {
        @for (var i = 0; i < Model.ChangeTypeList.Count; i++) {
            <div style="vertical-align:top" class="form-check form-check-inline col-3">
                <input asp-for="@Model.ChangeTypeList[i].IsSelected" data-changetypeid="@Model.ChangeTypeList[i].ID" data-changetypeidlisttodisable="@Model.ChangeTypeList[i].ChangeTypeListToDisableOnSelection" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" checked="@Model.ChangeTypeList[i].IsSelected" onchange="changeTypeSelectionChanged()" />
                <label asp-for="@Model.ChangeTypeList[i].IsSelected" class="form-check-label">@Model.ChangeTypeList[i].Name</label>
            </div>
        }
    } else {
        <span class="alert-danger">Could not load change type list.</span>
    }
</div>

So I can load all the possible change types.  But how do I store the selected(checked) items in
ChangeFormChangeType and have it persist through multiple posts? I have in the code behind:
[BindProperty] public List<ChangeFormChangeType> SelectedChangeTypes { get; set; } = new List<ChangeFormChangeType>();
But I am unsure how to handle this in the .cshtml file
I don't want to post on every checkbox changed event...
Am I best off just rebuilding List<ChangeFormChangeType> on every post and adding a bunch of
HTML.HiddenFor tags to represent all my properties in my ChangeType model then simply binding that?
eg posting this works:
/*
@Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.ChangeTypeList[i].ID)
@Html.HiddenFor(model => Model.ChangeTypeList[i].Name)
@Html.HiddenFor(repeated for other properties)

<input asp-for="@Model.ChangeTypeList[i].IsSelected" data-controlstodisable="@Model.ChangeTypeList[i].ChangeTypeListToDisableOnSelection" class="form-check-         input" type="checkbox" id="@Model.ChangeTypeList[i].ID" checked="@Model.ChangeTypeList[i].IsSelected" onchange="changeTypeSelectionChanged()" />
<label asp-for="@Model.ChangeTypeList[i].IsSelected" class="form-check-label">@Model.ChangeTypeList[i].Name</label>

*/
I want to be able to store selected items from changeType in changeFormChangeType and have it persist through multiple postbacks
Thank you for the response.  I will clarify:
ChangeType is a type of change.  Eg New Hire, Rehire, Termination, etc.
Its as simple as a primary key of CtID and name property
I still have not figured out how to properly setup relationships between models to represent the database.  None of the examples I seen work..
I guess that's my first issue before even getting into the form.... I was not clear on that part in my question...and its not 100% needed but this is what I would like to figure out in order to properly represent it in my form.
So in my form I currently have (in my form)
/*
List ChangeTypes
ChangeForm ChangeForm
and List which I must load from DB or update from ChangeTypes
*/
my mock repository for ChangefomrChangeType simply has a function called ByChangeForm(int cfID) to load The ChangeFormChangeTypes.  Ideally, late I will figure out how to wrap this in a transaction but that beyone the current scope of the question.  For now, I am just trying to figure out how to setup the relationship between models and then how to represent those in my form.  This is also a very complex single form I am showing a very small piece of.
Right now my models are completely separate but should be more like
/*
ChangeForm
------------------
CfID
other properties
`List<ChangeFormChangeType>`
and/or
`List<ChangeType>`

*/
ChangeFormChangeType
/*
List<ChangeForm>
List<ChangeType>
While its `List<ChangeForm>` I would only even need look at 1 
ChangeForm 
at a time

*/

Update
Based on your desciption , from my comprehension your model would be a one-to-many relationship with one-form-to-many-types. You'd better consider and express more clearly if the some batch of types could be related to different forms , then it would be many-to-many.
If one-to-many, the relationship is easy to set. EF Core provides a simple way to configure it.
I mocked some models and data.  Let's assume the changetypes are some worker information indicating their status.
Model.cs
public class ChangeType
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? ChangeTypeName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; } = false;
    public int ChangeFormId { get; set; }
    public ChangeForm? ChangeForm { get; set; }
}

public class ChangeForm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? FormName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<ChangeType> ChangeTypes { get; } = new List<ChangeType>();
}

DBContext.cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<ChangeForm>()
        .HasMany(e => e.ChangeTypes)
        .WithOne(e => e.ChangeForm)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.ChangeFormId)
        .IsRequired();
}

public DbSet<WebApplication81.Models.ChangeType> ChangeType { get; set; } = default!;
public DbSet<WebApplication81.Models.ChangeForm> ChangeForm { get; set; } = default!;

Index view of ChangeForm
@model IEnumerable<WebApplication81.Models.ChangeForm>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FormName)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FormName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Details</a> |
                    <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Delete</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @foreach (var type in item.ChangeTypes)
                    {
                        <text>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</text>
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => type.Id)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => type.ChangeTypeName)
                        @Html.DisplayFor(model => type.IsSelected)
                        <a asp-controller="ChangeTypes" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@type.Id">Edit</a>
                        <a asp-controller="ChangeTypes" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@type.Id">Details</a>
                        <a asp-controller="ChangeTypes" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@type.Id">Delete</a>
                        <br />
                    }
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

You can see the page of forms and types, whether 1 form or a list is ok. Only some logic in controller is needed for custom design.

Attention
The ChangeFormChangeType table is not necessary. If you want to create the table to store the key-foreign key pair , then modify the data through this, it is feasible too, only need some modification dealing with the database. However it is not as clear as the simple two tables
If I misunderstand your issue, please be free to tell me.

If you are meaning to set all the selected properties and then post, the tag-Helper HTML.HiddenFor way is feasible, so is the Javascript way. You only need to ensure to save to database after selected.
ChangeForm.cshtml
@page
@model ChangeFormModel

<form method="post">
    <div class="col-12 changeTypeList">
        @if (Model.ViewModel.ChangeTypeList != null && Model.ViewModel.ChangeTypeList.Any())
        {
            @for (var i = 0; i < Model.ViewModel.ChangeTypeList.Count; i++)
            {
                <div style="vertical-align:top" class="form-check form-check-inline col-3">
                    <input asp-for="@Model.ViewModel.ChangeTypeList[i].IsSelected" data-changetypeid="@Model.ViewModel.ChangeTypeList[i].ID" class="form-check-input change-type-checkbox" type="checkbox" onchange="changeTypeSelectionChanged(this)" />
                    <label asp-for="@Model.ViewModel.ChangeTypeList[i].IsSelected" class="form-check-label">@Model.ViewModel.ChangeTypeList[i].Name</label>
                    <input type="hidden" name="SelectedChangeTypes[@i].CtID" value="@Model.ViewModel.ChangeTypeList[i].ID" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="SelectedChangeTypes[@i].IsSelected" value="@Model.ViewModel.ChangeTypeList[i].IsSelected" class="hidden-is-selected" />
                </div>
            }
        }
        else
        {
            <span class="alert-danger">Could not load change type list.</span>
        }
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        function changeTypeSelectionChanged(checkbox) {
            var isSelected = checkbox.checked;
            var parentDiv = checkbox.closest('div');
            var hiddenField = parentDiv.querySelector('.hidden-is-selected');
            hiddenField.value = isSelected;
        }
    </script>
}

ChangeForm.cshtml.cs
public class ChangeFormModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly WebApplication78.Data.WebApplication78Context _context;
    public ChangeFormModel(WebApplication78.Data.WebApplication78Context context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public ChangeFormViewModel ViewModel { get; set; } = new ChangeFormViewModel();

    public void OnGet()
    {
        // Load data
    }

    public IActionResult OnPost()
    {
        foreach (var selectedChangeType in ViewModel.SelectedChangeTypes)
        {
            if (selectedChangeType.IsSelected)
            {
                // Add to ChangeFormChangeType
            }
            else
            {
                // Remove from ChangeFormChangeType if needed
            }
        }

        // Save to database
        // Data is saved after you finished the properties selected

        return RedirectToPage("Success");
    }
}

Or if you mean to selected and then do something else like nevigate to other pages to select some other properties, you could try localstorage or cookies.
        [BindProperty]
        public ChangeFormViewModel ViewModel { get; set; } = new ChangeFormViewModel();

        private const string CookieKey = "SelectedChangeTypes";

        public void OnGet()
        {
            // Load data
            var cookieValue = Request.Cookies[CookieKey];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cookieValue))
            {
                var selectedChangeTypes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ChangeFormChangeType>>(cookieValue);
                foreach (var changeType in ChangeFormViewModel.ChangeTypeList)
                {
                    var sessionItem = selectedChangeTypes.FirstOrDefault(s => s.CtID == changeType.ID);
                    if (sessionItem != null)
                    {
                        changeType.IsSelected = sessionItem.IsSelected;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

Then the selected status will be kept if your lcoalstorage or cookies are not cleared. Then save to database all together.


I cant use this site to save my life.  I updated my question.  Is more of a modeling question..sorry for the formatting.

@Greg S I have updated my answer based on my comprehension of your description , please check if it answers your question, if I misunderstand or if I am not clear , please let me know.
